# Django csrf verification failed despite all tokens being present

Tags: django, django-forms, django-csrf

I have a django website with forms. It works fine in debug mode on localhost but when a form is posted on a real server I get an csrf verification failed error. The form contains a csrf middleware token generated by `{%csrf_token%}` and the csrf token from the cookie is also sent with the request. The form is sent from subdomain.example.com/path to the same address. How can I fix this error?

Comment: You have to add `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`  and `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to your settings.py like so: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*.company.com','127.0.0.1', 'company.com']

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://*.company.com', 'http://*.company.com','https://*.127.0.0.1']`